# How to use `is`, listener object and property object in vue in jsx?

Tags: vue.js, jsx

```
//vue SFC
<component
  :is="comp"
  v-bind="props"
  v-on="listeners"
></component>
```

How to use `is`, listener object and property object in vue in jsx?
VUE 2

Comment: are you using vue 2 or 3?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim vue 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
  {createElement(comp,{
    props:{xxx:'xxx'},
    on:{eee:()=>{}}
  })}
</div>
```

Use `createElement` to create VNode directly.